# Sort words based on custom ordering

Tags: algorithm, sorting

User sets his own ordering, for example:

```
String s = "bawfedghijklmnopqrstuvcxyz"
```

And than he enter some words, like:

```
"aa", "bb","cc","dd"
```

Now I have to print the letters in the sorted form.

The output should be:

```
bb, aa, dd, cc
```

I don't have any clue how to proceed, can anyone help me out the with the way to proceed? Code is not required.

Comment: Give me back the minimal understanding thing.

Comment: every computer science problem can be solved by a bit of indirection. start by assigning alphabetic order number to each character. define comparison function. use it. hey presto, or "hey pesto!" as the italians say.

Comment: At least specify what language you are using. The other guy who posted the same question at least posted a code snippet and something saying it was his homework.

Comment: There are two questions here: (1) how to sort in general and (2) how to sort using custom order.  Which one is a problem for you?

Comment: One idea would be to implement the comparison function as the alfabetical_order_string.find(char)<alfabetical_order_string.find(char). Starting from left and proceeding to right until unequal.

Comment: Read a good textbook or at cppreference.com about the `std::sort` function and a custom comparator.

Comment: @ PM 77: I would guess custom order.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer:

First, recode them into regular sorting order. Eg. In your case, replace all "b" with "A", "a" with "B" and so on.

Sort it.

Decode according to your mapping. Eg. Replace all "A" with "b" etc

Comment: THe problem is how to sort using custom order.

Comment: Sir i am not asking for the code, i need just an idea how to proceed so language specification is not required as such. Although C++ and java both are fine..

Answer (score 1):

Each letter **x** has some index **k[x]** in your string **s** e.g. **b** has index **0**, 
**a** has index **1**, **w** has index **2** and so on (assuming the string **s** is 0-based).

So you need to sort your words based on the letter indexes as defined by **s** and 
not based on their 'normal'/'natural' indexes (where **a** would be **0**, and **b** would be **1**, 
**c** would be **2** and so on). So for example based on that ordering defined by **s** you 
have that: **b** < **a** (as **b** is mapped to **0** and **a** is mapped to **1**).

That's all this task asks you to do.

To start, take any sorting algorithm (for words), and implement it literally.
Then sorting algorithms have usually a point whey they compare two chars, there 
you have to consult the char indexes (as defined by **s**) and compare based on them.
That's the only change you need to make in the original implementation.

Answer (score 1):

by C

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int strcmp_custom(const char *s1, const char *s2){
    static const char *table="bawfedghijklmnopqrstuvcxyz";
    for ( ; *s1 == *s2; s1++, s2++)
        if (*s1 == '\0')
            return 0;
    if(islower(*s1) && islower(*s2))
        return strchr(table, *s1) < strchr(table, *s2) ? -1 : 1;
    else
        return *(unsigned char *)s1 < *(unsigned char *)s2 ? -1 : 1;
}

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    return strcmp_custom(*(const char **)a, *(const char **)b);
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I meant (but in C++).

Answer (score 0):

Just I have tried the following ways ...

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class Test {

        static Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        public static int compare(String one, String two) {
            int len1 = one.length();
            int len2 = two.length();
            int n = Math.min(len1, len2);
            char v1[] = one.toCharArray();
            char v2[] = two.toCharArray();
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;

            if (i == j) {
                int k = i;
                int lim = n + i;
                while (k < lim) {
                    char c1 = v1[k];
                    char c2 = v2[k];
                    if (c1 != c2) {
                        return map.get(String.valueOf(c1)) - map.get(String.valueOf(c2));
                    }
                    k++;
                }
            } 

            return len1 - len2;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String FORMAT ="bawfedghijklmnopqrstuvcxyz";
            char[] charString = FORMAT.toCharArray();

            for(int i=0; i<charString.length; i++){
                map.put(String.valueOf(charString[i]), i);
            }

            List<String> list = Arrays.asList("bw", "bb", "bd", "ba" ); // Input Strings

            for(int j=0; j<list.size(); j++){
                for(int k=j; k<list.size(); k++){
                    if(compare(list.get(j),list.get(k)) > 0){
                        String temp = list.get(j);
                        list.set(j, list.get(k));
                        list.set(k, temp);
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(list);
        }
    }
```

**Note :** If you want add capital letters, numbers and special characters in your input strings You have to add all the characters in FORMAT strings. I hope I will help you some what to go to next level ...